# AoT ngc and dynamic templateUrl

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I have been using dynamic templates URL in order to get multiple 'themes' to my application (HTML+CSS)
Unfortunately it works fine when developing (I had to tweak the way to retrieve my templateUrl in order to be able to compile).

But when compiling with ngc I get:
Error: No template specified for component MozaikApp

I have been struggling with that for ever now... Anyone can lead me of a nice way to make it work?

Comment: Can you share your component code.

Comment: That should sum it up:

https://plnkr.co/edit/dTFxRdo72CcVNXHmEqoY

Comment: Since you are reading the template file name through local storage, AOT will definitely fail to precompile the code to create a complete .ts file. I recommend if you want to have a particular theme template, then try to load the page by some function inside ngOnInit so that you get access to localStorage then

Comment: 'load the page by some function'? How should I do that?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to precompile BOTH themes somehow?

Comment: Create a dynamic component and initialize it using whatever condition you want. You just need to tell the main app component  in the entryComponent key within @Component metadata, the name of the dynamic compoennt. For more read here.. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader